# How can I constantly check if the value of a bool is true/false? SWIFT

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, boolean

Hello my problem is simple I have to constantly check whether the value of a bool is true or false, what I have tried so far is to use the:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)
```

function in swift and it is way to fast and once it checks the values it will constantly repeat the action even though I only wish for it to perform the action only once, so basically what I'm saying is that all I want to do is to check whether the bool value is true or false once and then stop checking until it changes again. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, please? What is this _value of a bool_? Is it a property in the same class or something else?

Answer (score 6):

**Property Observers**

You can use Property Observers in Swift to accomplish what you need... Here is what docs says about these:

> Property observers observe and respond to changes in a property’s
>   value. Property observers are called every time a property’s value is
>   set, even if the new value is the same as the property’s current
>   value.

There are `willSet` and `didSet` property observers:

- willSet is called just before the value is stored.
- didSet is called immediately after the new value is stored.

To solve your problem, you could do something like this:

```
 var myProperty:Int = 0 {

        willSet {
           print("About to set myProperty, newValue = \(newValue)")
        }

        didSet{
            print("myProperty is now \(myProperty). Previous value was \(oldValue)")
        }
    }
```

You can implement either one or both of property observers on your property.

**Getters and Setters**

As an alternative, You can use getters and setters on a stored property to solve your problem:

```
private var priv_property:Int = 0

var myProperty:Int{

    get {
        return priv_property
    }

    set {
        priv_property = newValue
    }
}
```

Computed properties do not actually store a value. Instead, they provide a getter and an optional setter to retrieve and set other properties and values indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should use observers or callbacks. Read comments below and see @Whirlwind's answer. The solution below is not really recommended since it would be inefficient and might complicate your code. But if you wanted or needed to do it in the `update()`, here's how I'd do it:

```
// Assume stored property
// It might be an API call and so on
var boolToWatch = false

var lastValueOfWatchedBool: Bool?
var lastCheck: TimeInterval = 0
let checkInterval = 1.0 // check every second

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {

    // In case boolToWatch is an expensive API call might be good to
    // check less frequently
    if currentTime - lastCheck > checkInterval {
        lastCheck = currentTime

        // Check for the initial case
        if lastValueOfWatchedBool == nil {
            lastValueOfWatchedBool = boolToWatch
        }

        // Detect change
        if boolToWatch != lastValueOfWatchedBool {
            lastValueOfWatchedBool = boolToWatch

            // Do what you need to do when the value changed here
            print("I feel different!")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Property observers are they way to do this. See Whirlwind's answer.

Comment: @SteveIves I know, but you are assuming it _is_ a property being mutated on the same instance. It might be a value that is a result of an expensive API call.

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing Depending on the type of an expensive API call, it can have for example a completion handler, or can post a notification once it is done, or can set some property to invoke its didSet observer... The point is, you don't have to check constantly (not even every second) for a change, but rather to take actions only once when property's value has been actually changed (which is, based on OP's question, what he was interested about).

Comment: @Whirlwind I get it. There are observers, callbacks, async etc. but sometimes they're not available and you just have to poll. OP did not make it clear what 'value of a bool' is.

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing Okay that make sense, but I can't really think of a real world example on iOS where API doesn't provide nothing like delegate, callback, return value, notification... And there is a KVO as well (it differs in implementation for Swift and Obj-C but it is there). Well, I guess we are going off - topic, but if you can find an real wolrd example of this I would like to hear it.